# Create custom Arc in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create semi-circle like below..

[image]

How can I create it with flutter. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to use `CustomPaint` widget

Comment: Ok but at least some hint. I am really new with custom designs

Comment: Like which point to which point I have to take

Comment: `CustomPaint` needs a painter: so you have to create a class that extends `CustomPainter` class, override its `paint()` method and do your drawing there - basically you have to study `Canvas` API documentation

Comment: Ok I will check@pskink

Comment: and when drawing with `Canvas` i would use `Canvas#drawPath` but it is up to you if you use `Path` or not